# How to add icon at the bottom right of the ImageView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create the layout as shown :

[with the curved at the boundary and a plus icon at the right bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdBpI.png)

This is what I did :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_five"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_placeholder"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my external file to give rounded corners named @drawable/custom_layout_five:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/offWhite"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

But I am only able to achieve partial i.e the icon can be placed at the right bottom with this code but not like the image I uploaded . Can anyone suggest how can I achieve the same ??

Thanks

Comment: try using constraint layout

Comment: play with `margins` and `paddings`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make layout background transparent and add a margin to image view with id img to achieve this design for example

[image: Design]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_placeholder"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It will not give me the rounded corners .

Comment: you can get rounded corners by adding xml shape to your image view as background

Comment: I tried that , but I am not getting rounded corners. Let me add to the question

Comment: You can put you image inside CardView or use CircleImageView library

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer, now try it

Create a xml file in drawable folder as round_back.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Now create this layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_five"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_back"  //add this
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_placeholder"/>
     
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi there ,I am only getting the rounded edges of layout and not of that of the imageview.